# Set Null в связные таблицы asp.net core, EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Добрый день у меня существует 3 таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть метод для удаления Country

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var country = await _context.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        _context.Countries.Remove(country);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Вопрос:Как мне засетить null в CountryId в связных таблицах
модель City

```
 public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

модель Advertisement

```
public class Advertisement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="incorrect information")]

    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Через Fluent Api `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);` - и при удалении оно вам само проставит null. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: А где мне это прописывать? в контексте? или в контроллере?

Comment: В контексте есть `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` - вот туда.

Comment: Спасибо! Понял)

Comment: Не хочу писать ответ не проверив на реальной базе, поэтому если не сообразите сами и никто не даст ответа раньше - посмотрю, когда будет побольше времени. А пока - почитайте матчасть: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/2.3.php

Comment: есть дополнительный вопрос, set null есть.. как мне удалить city при удалении country? поменять setNull на Cascade не идет так

Comment: Что значит "не идёт так"? И может быть вам стоит задать дополнительный вопрос?

Comment: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Cities_Countries_CountryId' on table 'Cities' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Это отдельный вопрос, совершенно другой. Он касается того, что у вас сразу два варианта каскада и EF не знает какой выбрать. Посмотрите на таблицу - они же закольцованы. Код приводите заново и не забудьте включить написанное в OnModelCreating - это будет важно при ответе. Давайте: один вопрос = отдельная тема.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869641/cascade-delete-related-tables-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Country)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Country)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>()
            .HasOne(p => p.City)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```