# Удаление связанных сущностей без включения каскадного удаления

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Код контроллера для удаления

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var country = await _context.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    _context.Countries.Remove(country);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Country.cs

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

City.cs

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как сделать, что бы при удалении Country удалялись City связанные с Country?

Comment: Вы же задавали практически идентичные вопросы? Я вам ещё под первым вопросом отписывался Через Fluent Api `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`. И, кстати, показанный экшн ничего не удаляет - он просто выводит, а в .core по умолчанию генерируется связка Delete + DeleteConfirmed

Comment: К сожалению, в Модели бд невозможно использовать Fluent Api, так как ругается SQL, поэтому надо делать другими способами из них либо триггером либо кодом.. выбрал кодом

Comment: Метод правил, не тот скопировал

Comment: То есть вас устраивает удаление в коде и мы [больше не разбираемся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869641/213987), как сделать структуру базы на основе fluent?

Comment: да, удаление в коде устроит, если менять Модель, переписывать очень много кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var country = await _context.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    var cities = await _context.Cities.Where(m => m.CountryId == id);
    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        _context.Cities.Remove(city);
    }

    _context.Countries.Remove(country);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Либо через `.RemoveRange()`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var country = await _context.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    var cities = await _context.Cities.Where(m => m.CountryId == id);
    _context.RemoveRange(cities );

    _context.Countries.Remove(country);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Пока понятно, как и что сделано? Если понятно - то оберните удаление в тразакцию, чтобы сохранить целостность базы:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var country = await _context.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        var cities = await _context.Cities.Where(m => m.CountryId == id);

        _context.RemoveRange(cities );

        _context.Countries.Remove(country);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        transaction.Commit();
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Так же, хочу обратить внимание, что вы помещаете в контроллер слишком много логики, обычно контроллеры стараются сделать более тонкими:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    var country = await this.CountryService.GetAsync(id);
    return this.View(country );
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    await this.CountryService.DeleteAsync(id);
    return this.RedirectToAction(nameof(this.Index));
}
```

Т.е. дёрнул сервис — отобразил представление. В add/edit добавляется ещё шаг валидации модели перед отправкой в сервис.

Контроллеры в общем - не место где пишут логику. У вас в контроллере смешалась логика как минимум двух разных слоёв. Поэтому если у вас учебный проект — то и так сойдёт, в реальном проекте лучше разбить на слои Domain - DataAccess - Application - (Web)UI.

Comment: Да, все good! Благодарен

Comment: @AK а не безопаснее сначала удалить города, а потом удалить страну? Собственно при настройке каскадного удаления, сервер сам удалит города.

Comment: системой не предусмотрена логика для удаления городов. только через страны..поэтому только так

Comment: Премного благодарен за разъяснения!!

Comment: @Monomax Я спросил топикстартера, не хочет ли он ["дожать" каскадное удаление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869641/213987), но видимо пока нет. Насчёт безопасности: безопасность нужно обеспечивать транзакциями, а вот насчёт порядка я действительно ошибся: удалить страну, у которой есть города не получится, скажет "нарушено ограничение внешнего ключа".

Comment: Да, код написан в блокнотике и я не уверен, что точно всё вопроизвёл. Например. По-моему в транзакции `.Commit()` - ненужная строчка, при using'е он сам закоммитит/откатит транзакцию. Не помню, надо будет поглядеть на досуге. И проверка токена в asp.net core вроде по умолчанию уже ставится.

Comment: @AK собственно под безопасно я подразумевал слово правильно.